# Start android app when GPS is used

Tags: android, gps

I want to have my service automatically started when the GPS is being used by any app, and stopped, when the GPS is no longer used. If possible, I want to avoid having my service running in the background.

Apparently, there is no broadcast intent for "GPS is activated", like there is for example for "boot completed". That would have been perfect to start my service. Another idea I had is to register a GpsStatus.Listener at the LocationManager, but I think my app has to be running in the background for that all the time (and needs autostart permission).

The reason why I want to do this is that I want to collect GPS status information when it is in use.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: there is no way such like that, you have to run at-least 1 background service for that...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate){
                super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                //Location methods
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationListener = new GpsLocationListener();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
    class GpsLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            **write  here methods for services when your GPS is active or working**
                Toast.makeText(context, "Location Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this requires the service to auto-start in order to register the listener, right? I would like to avoid that. For example, [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) does not require that permission.